# Sql is not giving output

Tags: sql

The below SQL is not giving any output. I think something is wrong with the SQL. Please help

```
SELECT *
  FROM customer_table a
 WHERE     dept_no = '234'
       AND (   EXISTS
                  (SELECT cust_name
                     FROM s_cart b
                    WHERE item_count > 30 AND b.cust_name = a.cust_name)
            OR EXISTS
                  (SELECT cust_name
                     FROM spc_cust c
                    WHERE c.cust_name = b.cust_name))
```

sorry..the above one is not the original query. My requirement is I need to give two conditions inside the Exists like "exists (condition 1 or condition 2)". so it needs give true value if either of the condition is true

Comment: Not even " MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0004 seconds.)" this one

Comment: What do you mean by "not giving output" ? The output of your dbms is disabled or your query return some null values ? btw wich dbms are you using ?

Comment: sorry..the above one is not the original query. My requirement is I need to give two conditions inside the Exists like                                              "exists (condition 1 or condition 2)". so it needs give true value if either of the condition is true

Answer (score 0):

Could be as simple as your last line `WHERE c.cust_name = b.cust_name` --> `WHERE c.cust_name = a.cust_name`...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `a.cust_name` instead of `b.cust_name` in `WHERE Clause`

May be something like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM   customer_table a 
WHERE  dept_no = '234' 
       AND ( EXISTS (SELECT cust_name 
                     FROM   s_cart b 
                     WHERE  item_count > 30 
                            AND b.cust_name = a.cust_name) 
              OR EXISTS (SELECT cust_name 
                         FROM   spc_cust c 
                         WHERE  c.cust_name = a.cust_name) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `WHERE c.cust_name = b.cust_name` with `WHERE c.cust_name = a.cust_name` because b alias in defined in other scope.